# AWS Cognito USER_PASSWORD_AUTH "Initiate Auth method not supported."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to do the following:

```
  AWSUtil.generateSecretHash('test@test.com', ClientId).then(SECRET_HASH => {
    return AWSUtil.Cognito.adminInitiateAuth({
      AuthFlow: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
      ClientId,
      UserPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
      AuthParameters: {
        USERNAME: 'test@test.com',
        PASSWORD: 'lamepassword123',
        SECRET_HASH
      }
    }).promise();
  })
  .then(resp => {
    console.log(resp)
  });
```

It will not return anything but `"Initiate Auth method not supported."`

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminInitiateAuth-property), this should work. What gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under the <kbd>**App Clients**</kbd> section, did you enable the box for your user pool that says:

```
[x] Enable username-password (non-SRP) flow for app-based authentication (USER_PASSWORD_AUTH)
```

Comment: I have the same problem explained in the question. And I have that box you've mentioned checked and still getting the error. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue - resolved it by using **AuthFlow `ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH`** rather than `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` per the [example here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1212).

Comment: Enable sign-in API for server-based authentication (ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH)

Answer (score 7):

In case of Serverless framework usage, the `ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` need to be added to the `ExplicitAuthFlows` node.

```yaml
Resources:
  CognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      # Generate a name based on the stage
      UserPoolName: ${self:provider.stage}-user-pool
      # Set email as an alias
      UsernameAttributes:
        - email
      AutoVerifiedAttributes:
        - email

  CognitoUserPoolClient:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
    Properties:
      # Generate an app client name based on the stage
      ClientName: ${self:provider.stage}-user-pool-client
      UserPoolId:
        Ref: CognitoUserPool
      ExplicitAuthFlows:
        - ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH # See also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpoolclient.html
        - ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
        - ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH
        - ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH
      GenerateSecret: false

# Print out the Id of the User Pool that is created
Outputs:
  UserPoolId:
    Value:
      Ref: CognitoUserPool

  UserPoolClientId:
    Value:
      Ref: CognitoUserPoolClient
```

Answer (score 0):

- Go to the Cognito Service
  [image]
- Then, select the app client
  [image]
- Finally, edit the authentication workflows
  [image]